# LinkedList using initializer_list

Tags: c++

So, i'm trying to initialize a LinkedList class using an initializer_list.

```
template<typename T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList(initializer_list<T> e){
    head_= new Node<T>(*e.begin());

    long intcheck = 0;
    T old;

    for (auto x : e){
        if(intcheck > 0){
            Node<T>* curr = new Node<T>(old);
            if(head_ == curr){
                head_->next_ = new Node<T>(x);
            }
            curr->next_ = new Node<T>(x);
        }

        old = x;
        intcheck = 1;
    }


}
```

I get a seg fault when trying to print head_->next_  (nothing wrong with my print function)

Comment: First of all, you should check whether the `initializer_list` is empty or not before dereferencing it. Next, write a plain old `for` statement that iterates over `[e.begin() + 1, e.end())`, and get rid of that `intcheck` stuff; this is not the right place for a range based `for`. Then, how is `if(head_ == curr)` ever going to be true for the code you've shown? That would explain why printing `head_->next_` crashes, you're never assigning anything to it. You need to rethink the logic of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: and please use smart pointer

Comment: the condition in `if(head_ == curr)` will never be true. but anyway, this loop guarantees to not insert the last value in the initializer list. is that really what you want? also consider changing the type of `intcheck` from `int` to `bool` and rename, but really, get rid of everything here and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you actually want the `SortedList` to be sorted. If so, this will accomplish that goal.  It bails out early if the `initializer_list` is empty, but still leaves the object in a rational state.

```
template<typename T>
SortedList<T>::SortedList(initializer_list<T> e) : head_{nullptr} {
    if (e.size() == 0)
        return;
    auto it = e.begin();
    for (head_ = new Node<T>(*it); it != e.end(); ++it) {
        Node<T> *n = new Node<T>(*it);
        Node<T> *curr;
        for (curr = head_; curr->next_ && curr->next_->data_ < *it; curr = curr->next_) 
            continue;
        if (*it < curr->data_) {
            n->next_ = curr;
            head_ = n;
        } else {
            n->next_ = curr->next_;
            curr->next_ = n;
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, here's the destructor I used to test:

```
template<typename T>
SortedList<T>::~SortedList() {
    while (head_->next_) {
        Node<T> *t = head_->next_;
        head_->next_ = t->next_;
        delete t;
    }
    delete head_;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code says that head_->next_ will always be it's default value (we can't see the Node constructor so I can't say what that is).

```
for (auto x : e){
    if(intcheck > 0){
        Node<T>* curr = new Node<T>(old);
        if(head_ == curr){
            head_->next_ = new Node<T>(x);
        }
```

It's OK do send your initializer list into the for loop this way.  If it's empty you will just exit the loop immediately.

However your `curr` pointer is allocated right there, while your `head_` pointer was allocated above.  They will therefore never be equal because you are comparing two pointers that you are allocating in the same function.